# Plot elements evenly around edge of viewport with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have a group of elements in the center of the page in a tag cloud formation, that once one of them is clicked, the tags themselves distribute evenly around the edge of the viewport leaving space in the center for content.

I'm not sure what would be the best approach for doing this since it's not necessarily distance from the center that matters, but finding the four edges of the viewport and placing the available tags relatively evenly around that rim.